# How to reference specific cell number for LOOKUP in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub submitFormBtn_Click()

    If timeOfArrival.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter time of arrival", vbCritical
    
    ElseIf poNumber.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid PO Number", vbCritical
    
    
    Else
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.DTPicker1.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.timeOfArrival.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.poNumber.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = "=LookupCSVResults(D3,Table_PurchaseOrderLine[POR],Table_PurchaseOrderLine[Product])"
        
        

    End With
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**What it does**

The code above, takes in the User Form Text Box values, and then inserts it into excel sheet for each available row.

**Problem**

This function `"=LookupCSVResults(D3,Table_PurchaseOrderLine[POR],Table_PurchaseOrderLine[Product])"` is the complication.

For every record inserted into Excel sheet, it is currently referencing to cell `D3` - how can I reference it to the cell to the left of it?

Current problem:

[image]

Should be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use `lrow`:

```
"=LookupCSVResults(D" & lrow & ",Table_PurchaseOrderLine[POR],Table_PurchaseOrderLine[Product])"
```

Comment: Quick one - would you know quick code to add in "All-round Border" for each inserted row?

Comment: I'd use the macro recorder, don't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: It's something like this: `With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With` but where would I place this code.

Comment: What range should be bordered?

Comment: The inserted row - from my original question.

Comment: `With .Cells(lRow, 1).Resize(,5)`, `.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)`, etc.

Comment: Compile error: `expected: end of statement` pointing at the `,` after the `5`

Comment: You may want to ask a new question.